# How to pass data in DOMDocument object inside PHP script to JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, php, dom

My PHP script creates and saves a file to local hard disk using `DOMDocument`'s `->load` and `->save` methods successfully.

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($data);
$dom->save($filename);
return $dom; // am I passing data to JavaScript here wrongly?
?>
```

This PHP script is called upon with `jQuery`'s `$.ajax` from another file:

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'script.php',
 type: 'GET',
 data: parameters,
 success: function(resp) {
  //var data = new Blob([resp], {type: 'text/xml});
  //textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
  //return textFile;
  console.log(resp);
}
});//ajax
```

I don't see anything in console. How to pass DOMDocument data from PHP script to JavaScript's AJAX call?

I also tried using `file_get_contents()` and returning it's result but same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to echo the result, not return it.

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($data);
$dom->save($filename);
echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes in your script.

First, you have to turn

```
$dom->save($filename);
```

into

```
$dom->saveHTML($filename);
```

As stated in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.domdocument.php), the save() method return an integer while saveHTML() return the content generated.

---

Then, you have to turn

```
return $dom;
```

into

```
echo $dom;
```

Indeed, if you want Javascript to get the content, you have to write it in the output (via the echo function), not return it; "return" doesn't write anything